# Equivalent of Python's 'with' in Julia?

Tags: julia

Does Julia have an equivalent of Python's `with`? Maybe as a macro? This is very useful, for example, to automatically close opened files.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a `do` block. Docs on do blocks are [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introducing_Julia/Controlling_the_flow#Do_block).

And here is an example of how to do the usual `with open(filename) as my_file` of Python in Julia:

```
open("sherlock-holmes.txt") do filehandle
  for line in eachline(filehandle)
      println(line)
  end
end
```

The above example is from the [Julia wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introducing_Julia/Working_with_text_files) too.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know the `do` block. Can't find it in the docs (http://docs.julialang.org/). I also learned that `open` can take a function as a first argument. Then it will apply the function to the file handle and automatically close the file after.

Comment: It's in the docs. Under the functions section: http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/functions/#do-block-syntax-for-function-arguments

Comment: The `do` block is just a convenient way of defining an anonymous function used as the first argument to `open`. Also, this is not restricted to `open`, it can be used with any function that accepts another function as first argument.

Answer (score 2):

Although the `do` block syntax does have certain similarities to Python's `with` statement, there is no exact equivalent. This is discussed in further detail in the GitHub issue "[`with` for deterministic destruction](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/7721)". The issue concludes that this structure should be added to Julia, although no syntax or plan for such is established.